# eliminar una ruta en php

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente codigo

```
<?php
    include '../home/user_validate.php';
    include '../home/fecha_hora.php';
    $esta_global = $_REQUEST['esta_global'];
    $actualizar =include 'update.php';
    $guardar = include 'save.php';

    echo $sql = "
        INSERT INTO auditoria (operador,accion,tabla,descripcion,fecha,hora)
        VALUES ('$code_usuario_global','$accion','banco','$mensaje','$fecha','$hora')";

    $rs = pg_query($sql);
    if ($rs){
        echo json_encode(array('success'=>true));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('msg'=>pg_result_error($rs)));
    }

?>
```

y necesito eliminar el include de save si se esta actualizando un registro o viceversa

en la parte de a vista dependiendo del caso le paso un valor para cuando se esta actualizando un registro y cuando el registro es nuevo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagino que si se está actualizando el registro, mandarás algún dato vía get o post para identificarlo en el script. En tal caso, podrías hacer algo así (presuponiendo que envías un parámetro llamado 'id' vía get):

```
if (!isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $guardar = include 'save.php';    
}
```